# Laravel eloquent relationships with foreign keys

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

Stuck on this one tonight...so I'm building a messaging system which is comprised of tables as seen in this schema: http://www.laravelsd.com/share/8nBZmc

So a user may post a job to which another user can send that user a message regarding that job. This triggers a conversation to be created, a message to be posted (containing the ID of the user who sent it) and the two user_id's to be added to the conversation_user pivot table as participants.

In terms of relationships well a job HasMany conversations but BelongsTo a user, a conversation HasMany messages and BelongsTo a job, messages BelongTo a conversation etc etc etc.

My question is based on the schema, how could I show the total number of messages which relate to a job? I.e. How do I get the job ID and filter all the conversations that match the ID and then count the number of messages against each conversation? Is this straying into Query Builder land as opposed to Eloquent? Obvious solution is add job_id to messages table but that's duplication and I'm now too stubborn :)

Comment: I can't view the link (at least not without logging in) please add the schema somehow *inside* the question.

Comment: I've amended the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
$jobId = 1;
$count = Message::whereHas('conversation.job', function($q) use ($jobId){
    $q->where('id', $jobId);
})->count();
```

Comment: It sure does work! As eloquent as Eloquent itself. I pass jobs to my view with this
$jobs = $this->job->getOwn(Auth::id()); followed by 
return view('myjobs.index', compact('jobs');
However how do I pass jobIds as an array into your code to load into a view? It's the last missing piece of the puzzle

Comment: You can use `$this->getOwn(...)->lists('id');`